# Rolagem automatica de itens com angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Eu tenho uma lista de itens, dentro de uma div, com a diretiva do angular ng-repeat. E preciso nessa lista, utilizar uma rolagem automática, semelhante a esta [DEMOSTRAÇÃO](http://nishadmenezes.github.io/super-treadmill.js/) (está, utiliza o plugin super-treadmill do jquery). Como posso fazer isso com angularJs (versão 1.6)?

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div ng-repeat="model in collection">
        <h1>{{model.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{model.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver criando um simples directive

```
app.directive('startTreadmill', function(){
     return {
         link: function(scope, element, attr){
              $(element).startTreadmill({ direction: "down"});
         }
     }
})


<div class="panel-body" start-treadmill>
    <div ng-repeat="model in collection">
        <h1>{{model.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{model.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```